# CheckBoxList databinding error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

I have been having some trouble loading the CheckBoxList with data. I have been getting some errors on the DisplayMember and ValueMember.

Here is my cod:.

```
Protected Sub LoadCBMembers(ByVal objDeptGUID As String)
    Try
        Dim myCBTable As New DataTable()
        With myCBTable.Columns
            .Add("DisplayName", GetType(String))
            .Add("TextValue", GetType(String))   '<<<< change the type of this column to what you actually need instead of integer.
        End With
        Dim lqMembers As New lqFireFighterConnectDataContext
        Dim GetMembers = From r In lqMembers.tbUsers
                         Where r.DeptGUID = objDeptGUID And r.TextFLag = True
                         Select r
        If GetMembers.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each foundMember In GetMembers
            myCBTable.Rows.Add(foundMember.FirstName & " " & foundMember.LastName, foundMember.CellPhone & "@" & foundMember.PhoneCarriers)
            '  cbMembers.Items.Add(foundMember.FirstName & " " & foundMember.LastName)
        Next
        With cbMembers
            .DataSource = myCBTable
            .DisplayMember = "DisplayName"
            .ValueMember = "TextValue"
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You're aware your code lacks a `cbMembers.DataBind` call, aren't you?  Also, you say you're getting errors:  which errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    With cbMembers
        .DataSource = myCBTable
        .DisplayMember = "DisplayName"
        .ValueMember = "TextValue"
        .DataBind()
    End With
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx), this method must be called explicitly. Not all controls require you to call `DataBind()` explicitly (for many it is called for you implicitly), but `CheckBoxList` is an exception.

Comment: Thank for the the info and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and for pointing me in the right direction.  i made a little tweek and it worked.

Comment: Here the tweek i had to make . With cbMembers
                .DataSource = myCBTable
                .DataTextField = "DisplayName"
                .DataValueField = "TextValue"
                .DataBind()
            End With